Performance issues and worker crashes when switching from Dataflow Runner v1 to v2 in Java Beam SDK
I've been running a data pipeline using Dataflow Runner v1 with the Java Beam SDK without any issues. Recently, we tried migrating the pipeline to Runner v2, but we encountered the following problems:

Worker crashes: We observe that the worker CPU usage suddenly drops to 0%, and then the VM dies.
Higher resource usage: The same pipeline consumes significantly more resources (CPU and memory) when run on Runner v2 compared to Runner v1.

I've attached two images showing the resource usage for the same pipeline under Runner v1 and Runner v2 for reference.
Runner v1:

Runner v2:

Both pipelines are running in parallel and handling the same traffic
We tried:

Checking the logs for any relevant errors or warnings—nothing stood out.

Monitoring various metrics, but we didn't find anything useful to explain the performance difference.
Questions:

Is this a known issue with Dataflow Runner v2?

Are there any known incompatibilities or specific functionalities that don't work well with Runner v2 in the Java Beam SDK?

Are there any optimization recommendations or additional steps we should take when migrating from Runner v1 to v2?

Any guidance or troubleshooting tips would be appreciated!



If this is for streaming, I would recommend not intentionally upgrading to runner v2; generally Dataflow defaults to v1 for streaming jobs because it is expected that most jobs not using v2 features will be more performant in a streaming context (as of today).
If it is for batch, I would recommend opening a ticket with Dataflow customer support (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/support/getting-support) to take a look, it will likely be challenging to provide much help without being able to look at the job in question more closely.
